# Preview videos in div using Jquery, WordPress oEmbed & Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, youtube, oembed

I'm fairly new to both jQuery and Ajax, and have faced a problem when trying to use WordPress oEmbed with the help of Ajax.

This is what I have in functions.php at the moment:

```
function ajax_magic() 
{
     wp_localize_script( 'function', 'display_videos', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

function get_video_link()
{
echo wp_oembed_get($_POST['link']);
die();
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'ajax_magic');

add_action('wp_ajax_get_video_link', 'get_video_link');
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
function display_video(input,output)
{
var link = document.getElementById(input).value;
 jQuery.ajax({
     url: display_videos.ajaxurl,
     type: 'POST',
    data:{
      action: 'get_video_link', // this is the function in your functions.php that will be triggered
      url: link
    },
    success: function(data){
      //Do something with the result from server
      $('#'+output).html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

The **input** option is the url to the video, the **output** option contains the ID of the div where the result of the ajax function should be echoed.

The url of the video is fetched from a form field when clicking a preview button (not the submit button).

Right now, nothing happens, but I can't see any errors in the Javascript Console.

As I said, I'm fairly new to this, so maybe I have missed something very basic, or something like that.

By the way, this is how I implement the javascript functions file (general.js) inside functions.php. This works, but maybe I need to do it another way to make Ajax work?

```
function lets_add_scripts() {
wp_register_script('general', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/general.js', array('jquery'),'', false);
wp_enqueue_script('general');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lets_add_scripts' );
```

Thanks for any help you can give me, it's greatly appreciated!

// Jens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to localize a non-existent script with the handle `function`. From the rest of your code it is clear you're targeting `general`. Not sure why you hook into `template_redirect` to localize, just add the localization part after the enqueue:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lets_add_scripts' );
function lets_add_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'general', get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/js/general.js', array( 'jquery' ),'', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'general' );
    wp_localize_script( 'general', 'display_videos', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
```

Comment: Additionally, in your ajax callback, you should work with `$_POST['url']` instead of `$_POST['link']`

Comment: Thanks a lot @diggy, that totally did the trick! Thanks for helping out a confused beginner like myself! :)